# Creating process mining diagrams in R

Tags: r, process-management, processmodel

I am new to Process Mining and was conducting study to create process maps in R. I wrote the following script with loaded packages but cannot observe the plot. Now, while installing the processMapR package, I get an error mentioned below the script. Please help and also please tell me few good packges for process mining in R.

```
install.packages("bupaR")
install.packages("edeaR")
install.packages("eventdataR")
install.packages("processmapR")
install.packages("processmonitR")
install.packages("xesreadR")
patients %>%
filter_trim(start_activities = "Registration", end_activities =  c("MRI 
SCAN","X-Ray")) %>%
process_map(type = performance())

Error:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
vI[[j]]) : 
namespace 'grDevices' 3.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'DiagrammeR'
* removing 'C:/Users/ashminkaul/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/DiagrammeR'
```

Comment: I have the latest version of R installed on my system.

Answer (score 1):

DiagrammeR needs to have grDevices 3.4.0. Try installing the latest version in a clean r-session.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the libraries after installation.
With `library(bupaR)` or `require(bupaR)` you load the functions in your environment. You have to do that in order to use the functions of those packages.

Just `install.packages("bupaR")` is not sufficient.